# Stackpanel in style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, stackpanel

Using next block of code in windows.resource.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="l1" >
    <Setter Property="Button.Effect" >
    <!--<Setter Property="BitmapEffect">-->
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Content" >
        <Setter.Value >
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Resources\find.bmp" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
                <TextBlock>Find</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It works only for one button, but as soon as I aply it to second button error generating during run-time.

```
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,25,0,0" Name="Button18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource l1}" />
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="586,37,0,0" Name="Button19" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource l1}" />
```

any solution for resolve this problem?

Comment: What error do you actually get ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the `Content` of a `ContentControl` directly this way. The reason for this is that the `StackPanel` (to name just one) in your `Content` setter is the same instance for all buttons that the style applies on; however, this is not allowed (and probably results in you getting the *Element is already the child of another element* exception).

Instead, you should set the `ContentTemplate` property:

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Resources\find.bmp" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
                <TextBlock>Find</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

This will work because now a new visual tree branch will be created for each instantiation of the template (i.e. there will be as many `StackPanel`s etc as you have buttons).

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the content of a control through a style like that (at least not twice).

You should use a template to sent the content, like so:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Resources\find.bmp" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
            <TextBlock>Find</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="l1" >
        <Setter Property="Button.Effect" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" />
    </Style>
```